# Indexing and retrieving data using index for a 3D grid for interpolation in c++

Tags: c++11, stl, interpolation

I have a 3D Cartesian grid data that needs to be used to create a 3D regular mesh for interpolation method. x,y & z are 3 vectors with data points that are used to form this grid. My question is, how can i efficiently give 2 index to these points say,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUfw6.png]

where c000 is indexed as 1 point (1,1,1), c100 is indexed as 2 for (2,1,1) for (x,y,z)

coordinate points and another index to identify the 8 points forming the cube. Say if I have a point C, I must retrieve the nearest 8 points for interpolation. so for points c000,c100,c110,c010,c001,c101,c111,c011 point index and cube index. Since the data available is huge, the focus is to use faster implementation. pls give me some hints on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

**About the maths:**

Identifying the cube which a point p surrounds requires a mapping

```
U ⊂ ℝ+**3 -> ℕ: 
p' (= p - O_) -> hash_r(p');
```

"O_" being located at (min_x(G),min_y(G),min_z(G)) of the Grid G.

Along each axis, the cube numbering is trivial.

Given a compound cube number

```
n_ = (s,t,u)
```

and N_x, N_y, N_z being the size of your X_, Y_, Z_, a suitable hash would be

```
hash_n(n_) = s 
               | t * 2**(floor(log_2(N_x))+1) 
                 | u * 2**(floor(log_2(N_x)) + floor(log_2(N_y)) + 2).
```

To calculate e.g. "s" for a point C, take

```
s = floor((C[0] - O_)/ a)
```

"a" being the edge length of the cubes.

**About taking that to C++**

Given you have enough space to allocate

```
(2**(floor(log_2(max(N_x, N_y, N_z)))+1)**3
```

buckets, a `std::unordered_map<hash_t,Cube>` using that (perfect) hash would offer O(1) for finding the cube for a point p.

A lesser pompous `std::map<hash_t,Cube>` using a `less` based on that hash would offer O(log(N)) find complexity.